# Issues with text geometry in Threejs

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to render some 3d text using THREE.FontLoader. The object is in the scene but does not appear. The only thing I thought could be the problem is that the mesh appears to have a BufferGeometry instead of a TextGeometry, for whatever reason. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Link to my code:

https://puu.sh/w78xs/3e350985e1.png

Comment: do you have a light source in your scene, as you use `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you have lights in your scene, and you camera is oriented correctly.

The `loader.load` call is asynchronous, but you're creating your mesh synchronously.

```
// This is an asynchronous call, which may take some time.
loader.load('/assets/delvetiker_regular.typeface.json', 
    function(font){
        // This function is a callback, and is only executed AFTER load completes
        geometry = ...;
    });

//...

// At this point, geometry MAY OR MAY NOT EXIST.
// If it doesn't, this won't work.
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mat);
```

If you move all the code you have at the bottom to *inside* your the loader callback, you should see a difference.

```
// This is an asynchronous call, which may take some time.
loader.load('/assets/delvetiker_regular.typeface.json', 
    function(font){
        // This function is a callback, and is only executed AFTER load completes
        geometry = ...;
        mat = ...'
        // At this point, geometry DOES EXIST.
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mat);
        super(...);
    });

//...
```

I'm also assuming the call to `super` adds the mesh to the scene, but if it doesn't, you'll also need to call `scene.add(mesh)` in the loader callback.

Answer (score 0):

Buffergeometry isn't the issue. If you look at the source, most THREE.XxxxXxxxxGeometry uses BufferGeometry somewhere behind the scenes.

First thing i saw is you have no lights in your scene. Try `MeshBasicMaterial` to make sure it's working. `Phong` expects lights. MeshBasicMaterial will just paint it a flat color.

Also make sure that your camera is not positioned inside the model and then also call `camera.lookAt(textmesh.position);` to make sure it's not looking away.